# Comma “A second before…”

Tags: commas

I’m wondering if the comma placed before “he” in the sentence below is correct.

> A second before the blast wave hit the bridge and ripped it apart, he jumped back.

Comment: Hello, D3merzel. It's optional, and as the 'introduction' contains 13 words including two verbs, I'd use it to help parsing by highlighting where the independent clause begins.

Comment: As Edwin points out, this is a style issue, and not grammar.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ — Yes, and... what’s wrong with that? From the EL&U Tour: *Ask about... Spelling and punctuation*.

Comment: But, as a matter of style, perhaps we don’t have time for a comma. It’s omission might make all the difference as to whether he survives or not. I’d be willing to break a style prescription here for effect.